# Find Area Problem

Tags: geometry

I came up wit this Geometry problem:

[My Problem & Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXmYR.png)

Is my solution correct?

(This is not Homework or something, I just came up with this problem)

Also, does the shape of the green Area have a name? If so, what is it? (If there is one)

Comment: Correct. $100-25\pi$

Comment: @CYKwong So my solution is correct. (Because 100 - 25π  ≈ 21.4601837). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

---

Area of the square  $$A = 20^{2}$$
Area of the circles $$C=4 \pi 5^{2}$$

Total deficit area $$D= A-C = 400-100 \pi$$

Area of green region $$\frac{D}{4} = 25 (4 - \pi) \approx 21.4602$$

[image: final]

Answer (score 3):

Also note that the gray area in this image is the same as the green area:
[image]

Comment: Ah yes. Thanks!